# What's the type of read() function's return value?

Tags: python, byte

I wanna read first 188 bytes from a binary file, and check whether the first character is `0x47`. Code below:

```
import os
fp=open("try.ts","rb")
for i in range(100):
  buf=fp.read(188)
if buf[0]=="\x47":
  print "OK"
fp.close()
```

But it gives:

```
if buf[0]=="\x47":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

My questions are:

1. What's the type of a return value in `read()` function?
2. How can I get the first character in a string or array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if buf[0]=="\x47":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

That means your `buf` is empty. You overwrote it 100 times in your loop. The file probably doesn't have 18800 bytes in it. At the end of a file `read` just returns an empty string. Did you mean to put your `if` inside the `for`? If so, indent it accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. What's the type of a return value in read() function?

You mean the method `read` of type `file`. The command `help(file.read)` gives:

> `read([size])` -> read at most size bytes, **returned as a string.**
>
> If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
>    Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
>    may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.

---

> 2. How can I get the first character in a string or array?

Just like you did, `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion when using sequence types: 
instead of using the exact index, it could be more useful using a slice. A slice always exists, even if the object is empty.

buf[0:1] returns the same of buf[0] when non empty, and it returns a empty string '' if buff is an empty string, while buf[0] returns an error (since it is empty, the first character doesn't exist)

And a string is False only when empty