# AttributeError when rewriting code so it works in Python 3.4

Tags: python

I am trying to alter the code below so that it works in `Python 3.4`. However, I get the Error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'` in the line `line.replace(",", "\t")`. I am trying to understand how to rewrite this part of the code.

```
import os
import gzip
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

baseURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file="
filename = "data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"
outFilePath = filename.split('/')[1][:-3]

response = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = BytesIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read())

compressedFile.seek(0)

decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb') 

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read().decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))

#Now have to deal with tsv file
import csv


csvout = 'C:/Sidney/ECB.tsv'

outfile = open(csvout, "w")
with open(outFilePath, "rb") as f:
    for line in f.read():
        line.replace(",", "\t") 
        outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You're writing ASCII (by default) with the `'w'` mode, but the file you're getting that content from is being read as bytes with the `'rb'` mode. Open that file with `'r'`.

And then, as Sebastian suggests, just iterate over the file object with `for line in f:`. Using `f.read()` will read the entire thing into a single string, so if you iterate over that, you'll be iterating over each character of the file. Strictly speaking, since all you're doing is replacing a single character, the end result will be identical, but iterating over the file object is preferred (uses less memory).

Let's make better use of the `with` construct and go from this:

```
outfile = open(csvout, "w")
with open(outFilePath, "rb") as f:
    for line in f.read():
        line.replace(",", "\t") 
        outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

to this:

```
with open(outFilePath, "r") as f, open(csvout, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in f:
        outfile.write(line.replace(",", "\t"))
```

Also, I should note that this is much easier to do with find-and-replace in your text editor of choice (I like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)).

Comment: Additionally try ``for line in f:`` instead of ``for line in f.read():``.

Comment: Can we please add the output file to a context manager?  `with open(outFilePath, "r") as f, open(csvout, "w") as outfile:`

Comment: @SebastianHöffner, suggestion implemented. Shouldn't alter the output, but it's a better practice.

Comment: @ChristopherPearson, I cleaned up the code to make better use of `with`.

Comment: Sweet.  that looks much better!  I don't think I had ever seen anybody write `open(foo)...  with open(bar)...  close(foo)` before.  I had to read the question code a couple of times to make sure I was reading it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting it as this:

```
with open(outFilePath, "r") as f:
    for line in f:   #don't iterate over entire file at once, go line by line
        line.replace(",", "\t") 
        outfile.write(line)
```

Originally you were opening it as a 'read-binary' `rb` file, which returns an integer (bytes), not a string as you were expecting. In Python, int objects do not have the `.replace()` method, however the string object does. This is the cause for your `AttributeError`. Ensuring that you open it as a regular 'read' `r` file, will then return a string which has the `.replace()` method available to call.

Related post on return type of `.read()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037390/whats-the-type-of-read-functions-return-value-in-python) and more information available from the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).